# How to wait for gettext not to be empty for an element

Tags: automated-testing, protractor, waits

I want to make sure the getText returns a non-empty string before continuing the program flow.

**I have tried :**

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
await browser.wait(EC.not(EC.textToBePresentInElement($('#result'), '')), 5000);
```

**my div looks similar to:**

```
<div id="result">5</div>
```

But the browser.wait always passes as the empty character is considered to be included in every string:

```
console.log('teststring'.includes('')) //always returns true
```

Could someone let me know the correct way to wait till the text is present in an element? I cannot wait for a specific text as the text changes according to inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through the source code of the expected condition,

Thee browser.wait expects a promise that resolves to a condition, so i created a promise that resolves to true of getText()==='', else false:

**So the solution is :**

```
let textNotToBePresentInElement= function (elem,text)  {

    return async()=> {
    let textreceived=await elem.getText();
    let bool=textreceived === text;
    return !(bool);
    }
  },


 await browser.wait(textNotToBePresentInElement(resultElement,''), 5000, "Result is empty even afer 3 sec");
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

```
async waitForElementTogetText() {
  await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
  *your code here*
  await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Can you also explain why thi code works? Your post would be much more helpful to others.